# File read to DB insert resulting in unicode strings

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am reading a JSON string from a file, parsing it, then inserting the data into a MySQL database. My insert query is throwing the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xE3\xADs' for column 'fname' at row 1
```

I believe the content causing the error is the `í` in the name `Ailís` (I echoed IDs until the error was thrown).

- The file is UTF8 encoded
- I am reading the file using a UTF8 context
- I am checking the encoding of the data to be UTF8 (it is)
- My PDO connection has a UTF8 charset, as well as `SET NAMES utf8`
- The database is UTF8 encoded
- The table is UTF8 encoded
- The column is UTF8 encoded

Code:

```
$opts = ['http' => ['header' => 'Accept-Charset: UTF-8, *;q=0']];
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$post = file_get_contents('sample_data/11111a_json_upload.json',false, $context);
if(!mb_check_encoding($post, 'UTF-8'))
    throw new Exception('Invalid encoding detected.');
$data = json_decode($post, true);
```

I also inserted the following function before I decoded the JSON:

```
static function clean_unicode_literals($string)
{
    return preg_replace_callback('@\\\(x)?([0-9a-zA-Z]{2,3})@',
        function ($m) {
            if ($m[1]) {
                $hex = substr($m[2], 0, 2);
                $unhex = chr(hexdec($hex));
                if (strlen($m[2]) > 2) {
                    $unhex .= substr($m[2], 2);
                }
                return $unhex;
            } else {
                return chr(octdec($m[2]));
            }
        }, $string);
}
```

When I read the raw file, and when I echo the parsed data to the browser, the name appears correctly. I assume therefore the issue is somewhere in my connection?

I create a new PDO instance like so:

```
public function __construct($db_user, $db_pass, $db_name, $db_host, $charset)
{
    if(!is_null($db_name))
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $db_host . ';dbname=' . $db_name . ';charset=' . $charset;
    else
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $db_host . ';charset=' . $charset;

    $options = [
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE    => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"
    ];

    try
    {
        $this->db_handler = new PDO($dsn, $db_user, $db_pass, $options);
        $this->db_handler->exec('SET NAMES utf8');
        $this->db_valid = true;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        $this->db_error = $e->getMessage();
        $this->db_valid = false;
    }

    return $this->db_valid;
}
```

(SET NAMES is there twice as I'm troubleshooting...)
The database, table, and column charsets are set to `utf8_general_ci`.

My IDE is PHPStorm, and I am running WAMP MySQL 5.7.14 on Windows 10.

Comment: So where is the code that actually does the insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is definitely wrong with that input string: `\xE3\xADs`

The first nibble `E` indicates that it should be a 3-byte UTF-8 sequence, but there are only two bytes.

And it's definitely not the `í` as thats the two-byte sequence `\xC3\xAD`.

I have to wonder why you've got that `clean_unicode_literals` function in there at all as all JSON strings and documents are supposed to be valid UTF-8 according to the JSON spec.

Try removing the `clean_unicode_literals` calls, and if you're still getting an error then the source data is corrupt.